# createBlockBlobFromLocalFile upload mp4 file to azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm want to upload mp4 file to my azure storage without md5 content.

```
    var uploadOptions = {};
    uploadOptions.storeBlobContentMD5 = false;
    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('kovach', fileName, files.file.path,uploadOptions, function(error, result, response) {
        if(!error){
        // file uploaded
            console.log(result);            
            res.end(fileName);
        }
    });
```

but in the response I got value in content md5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload a local file larger than 32MB, the `blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile` method actually invokes several REST calls:

1. Create a new block blob.
2. Put blocks.
3. [Commit the block list](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/v2.1.0/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L5296).

From the [Put Block List REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/put-block-list), the Content-MD5 header is returned so that the client can check for message content integrity. This header refers to the content of the request, meaning, in this case, the list of blocks, and not the content of the blob itself.

I think you try `blobsvc.getBlobProperties`, you won't see content-md5 set on this blob.